# Can a dog run 150 km non-stop?

Tags: dogs

In Werner Herzog's 2010 documentary *Happy People: A Year in the Taiga*, a dog is reported to run 150 km from the Taiga back to the owner's village, without any stop and seemingly at full speed as it is running next to a snowmobile.

I am skeptical of this. I cannot find any reports of dogs running a distance even close to this. [This article on super-distance dogs](https://www.runnersworld.com/advanced/a20836779/super-distance-dogs/) does not mention any distances over 40 miles (64 km), which is still less than half the distance, and together with the owner running, so at much lower speed.

Can a dog really run 150 km at full speed?

Answer (score 1):

There are 100, 200 and 1000 mile races for huskies, we can check the speeds of the winners of the races: http://www.eaglecapextreme.com/index.php/the-race/race-times

97 miles run in 17.23 hours, gives 5.6 miles an hour, 10 km/h, on a cold day, 12-16 dogs towing the musher and the sledge. without a sledge, a husky can probably run 150km at 15km/h average, so that's 10 hours of running.

there have been studies about husky mitochondria and their biology.